# $.getJSON() returns old (cached?) data

Tags: jquery, request

I'm using the following code to do a simple ajax call, but it keeps logging an old value for the reportData.report (ie. it works once, and then never seems to update).

```
var noCache = new Date().getTime();
$.getJSON(url, {"noCache": noCache, cache: false}, function(reportData) {
    console.log(reportData.report);
```

However, the array logged in the console is different from the response to the GET request I can see in Firebug. I tried to do it with the $.ajax function, as well as disabling caching (also added a random parameter to make sure its not cached). The fact that I do see the correct (updated) response in Firebug makes me think this is not the problem.

How come it keeps logging the old data?

EDIT: I'm using latest version of Firefox to test if that makes any difference

EDIT2: I think it may have something to do with the UUIDs im getting back (example: 23766330297548822). Could it be that these are rounded off incorrectly in javascript? How would I retrieve this integer (perhaps as a string?) correctly from the JSON data?

Comment: if you see updated data in response, problem is likely elesewhere in handling of response

Comment: But I log the reportData on the first line in the callback. How can it go wrong?

Comment: is the object being manipulated after you log it? What you see in console will be the live object and it will reflect any changes you make to it even after it is logged

Comment: I only read from the object afterwards, like so:

report = reportData.report;
for (var i = 0; i < report.length; i++) { var report_uuid = report[i].uuid; ... etc.

Comment: and that code is also within the complete callback? Is `report` declared using `var`? SHow more code in question

Comment: Could it have something to do with integers being too big? I'm sending a UUID (ie. 23766330297548822), and I notice that the numbers are always slightly off (either higher or lower), when comparing the logged number and the number in the request response.

Answer (score 0):

Large numbers in Javascript are not accurate enough, so you should not rely on them. Try this:

```
var a = 23766330297548822;
var b = 23766330297548824;
console.log(a === b); // Returns true :)
```

It will say that `a` and `b` are equal, but that is not true.

Try to work with strings or use a bigint library like [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum).

Comment: The variable in the returned JSON object is a large number, what would be the best way to accurately store it as a string in javascript? I tried var report_uuid = '' + (reportData.report[i].uuid); and var report_uuid = (reportData.report[i].uuid).toString(); but both do not work

Comment: It should be done in the json file you are requesting. If that JSON is third party then try to tell them about this problem with large numbers. Or take a look to this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-bigint